# Idempotence and Random Variables in Ansible

Tags: cron, ansible

Is there a way to guarantee idempotence for playbooks that use randomly generated variables?

For example, I want to setup my crontabs to trigger emails on multiple servers at different times, so I create random integers using ansible's set_fact module:

```
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      first_run_30="{{ 30 | random }}"
    run_once: yes
```

Then apply those generated variables to my crontab using ansible like so:

```
   - name: Setup cron30job
    cron: name=cron30job minute={{first_run_30}},{{first_run_30 | int + 30}} job='/bin/bash /cron30job.sh' state=present user=root
    environment:
      MAILTO: 'me@somelist.com'
      MAILFROM: 'me@somehost.com'
```

This works very well, however, ansible's indempotence principle is, I believe, broken using this strategy because each time a play is made you see a change:

```
TASK: [Setup cron30job] ***************************************** 
changed: [127.0.0.1]
```

Further, in the crontab checking under root each time during three separate runs:

```
[ansible]# cat /var/spool/cron/root 
#Ansible: cron30job
5,35 * * * * /bin/bash /sw/test/cron30job.sh
#Ansible: cron30job
9,39 * * * * /bin/bash /sw/test/cron30job.sh
#Ansible: cron30job
6,36 * * * * /bin/bash /sw/test/cron30job.sh
```

If there is a workaround, or maybe indempotence just will not be possible in my scenario, I would like to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a random value, you could get something related to the node, like an hash of the hostname or the last byte of the ip address.

This is an example:

```
- name: Get a pseudo-random minute 
  shell: expr $((16#`echo "{{inventory_hostname}}" | md5sum | cut -c 1-4`)) % 30
  register: minute
  changed_when: false
```

Comment: Even though this is the only suggestion, it seems like the most reasonable solution. However, I need to point out that the  task `Get a pseudo-random minute` will report the `[changed]` status. I recommend adding `changed_when: false` to prevent this from happening. Circumventing it in this instance is fine because we guarantee indempotence for the crontab and we know that the hashed value will not change for each machine, unless you change the host name for that ip (which is a matter of its own).

Comment: This is great, but I had two problems. First, expr didn't work with the default shell (/bin/sh)  on debian, which I think is dash. adding `args: executable: /bin/bash` helped with that. Second, expr has an exit code of 1 if the output is 0. `failed_when: "minute.rc == 2 or minute.rc == 3` fixes that, by not failing on exit code 1.

Answer (score 27):

As of Ansible version 2.3, it’s possible to initialize the random number generator from a seed. This way, you can create random-but-idempotent numbers:

```
"{{ 59 |random(seed=inventory_hostname) }} * * * * root /script/from/cron"
```

Source: [random number filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#random-number-filter)

I've used this pattern to produce random cron start times with:

1. different minutes on different target servers
2. different minutes for different days on the same server (randomness)
3. the same minute for the same day and server when repeatedly running Ansible (idempotence)

Requires Ansible >=2.3:

```
 cron:
    name: "{{some_name}}_{{item.day}}"
    state: present
    job: "{{some_job}}"
    weekday: "{{item.day}}"
    hour: "{{item.hour}}"
    minute: "{{59|random(seed=inventory_hostname + item.dow)}}"
  with_items:
 - { day: 0, hour: 3, dow: "sunday" }
 - { day: 1, hour: 7, dow: "monday" }
 - { day: 2, hour: 1, dow: "tuesday" }
 - { day: 3, hour: 5, dow: "wednesday" }
 - { day: 4, hour: 2, dow: "thursday" }
 - { day: 5, hour: 4, dow: "friday" }
 - { day: 6, hour: 7, dow: "saturday" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't have `ansible >= 2.3` available, a hashed approach using jinja2:

```
{{ (inventory_hostname |hash('md5')|int(0, 16)) % 60 }}
```