# Change cron entry with Ansible without changing time

Tags: cron, ansible

I have a bunch of systems, with a Cron-scheduled job on them, which was set up by Ansible. Checking the crontab, I can see

```
#Ansible: Job Name
0 22 * * * /path/to/script.sh >/var/log/folder/script.log
```

I need to change that entry to point to a different script. This is easy enough, except that some of the systems in question have had the timing changed, and I need to preserve that changed timing. I tried an ansible task without the timing:

```
- name: Update Cron
  cron:
    name: Job Name
    job: /path/to/new/script.sh >/var/log/folder/script.log
```

But that of course just left the following, since each time option defaults to '*':

```
#Ansible: Job Name
* * * * * /path/to/new/script.sh >/var/log/folder/script.log
```

Is there any good way to get Ansible to update the cron entry without clobbering the current timing, or possibly a clean way to read it up and tell Ansible to write out the current time? Or am I going to have to fall back on something ugly and probably-not-recommended like using the lineinfile module to edit the appropriate /var/spool/cron/ files directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible only with the cron module. But I see a way to do it cleanly and to get a chance to enhance your inventory at the same time.

1. use the `command` module with `crontab -l`.
2. parse the `stdout_lines` to find the cron name comment, the definition is on the next line
3. parse the cron definition to extract the schedule. Store this in var(s)
4. optionally update you host_vars in your inventory with those values so you have the schedule for a next run if needed
5. run the `cron` module with the parsed schedule.

I admit that's a lot of steps for something that is normally done with a single task but this is the only clean way I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some sort of logical grouping of your hosts, rather than parsing each host for the crontab entry, can you setup the times per-group then setup the groups in the inventory to set the times using the "cron:" module?

If you need to ensure that there is some randomness to the time entries (so you don't have 500 hosts all trying to upload a log file at the same second), you can use the "random" filter along with a seed as shown in this StackOverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946949/187426